# logging file zero extension

Tags: spring, slf4j

I am creating a spring application and I have a problem with slf4j. When logging in to the file, a file with the extension zero (.log.0) is created and a few irrelevant lines are saved there and end. At the next start of the application the previous file has the extension .log.1 and the new one again .log.0. I have the login level set to "debug" in the properties and the login file name to "xxx.log". Anyone got any idea for this?
regards

Comment: Which version of Spring? Spring or Spring Boot ? Your config ?

Comment: I only have logging.file = logs / xxx.log in the application.properties file and the simplelogger.properties org.slf4j.simpleLogger.defaultLogLevel = debug file. Springboot. ver 1.5.10 in another project I have identical settings etc. and it works fine. I think I missed something somewhere in this project

Comment: You set it up to roll the log. Post your configuration xml so we can help you fix it.

Comment: I don't set rolling anywhere. To test, I created a new empty project and moved all files and logs work normally there. I have no idea why not in the original project.